# How to set an integer value to a lable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method which returns and integer value. But i can't display the value using a label. Here I have added the code.I get and **error message** as follows.

> Error 4   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Here is my code

```
int ddlValue = Int32.Parse(ddlAppealList.SelectedValue.ToString());
lblCompNameDisplay.Text = cs.compName(ddlValue).ToString();
```

**cs** is an object from a class.

Comment: Are you sure the `ddlAppealList.SelectedValue` is an integer one?

Comment: why can't you use directly `ddlValue` ? any issue with this ?

Comment: Where do you get the exception, in which line exactly? What is `compName`?

Comment: @user6592730 what is the value you getting `ddlValue` at the time of debugging

Comment: There was a little problem with getting value. And i could fix it. Now i hava another problem.  Is it possible to get data from datatable like this?      string comName = db.getCom(name).Rows[0].ToString();

Comment: What do you want to store in `comName` ? The content of the first row (converted into a string...), or the content of a specific cell of the first row ?

Comment: From  the query only one string value will be taken. And i want to store that string into a comName

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your question, you are trying to convert a string to integer. But for doing that, **your string must be in proper format(such as "123").** If it's not in proper format then Int32.Parse method gives error *"cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"*.

Try following code and add a breakpoint at line 2:
When breakpoint is hit, check value of `outputString`

```
//Line 1:
var outputString = ddlAppealList.SelectedValue.ToString();

//Line 2:
int ddlValue = Int32.Parse(outputString);

//Line 3:
lblCompNameDisplay.Text = cs.compName(ddlValue).ToString();
```

You may be getting this error because value of outputString is not in proper format. Try to fix that.

Comment: Im not setting the selected value to the label. Value we select to is parameter to a method which deals with database. An that method returns a dataset.(I've modified the code. Therefore it's little bit different from the previous one) If you can help me to get the value from dataset and store it to a label

Comment: My answer is still the same. Debug it in the way I've specified in my answer and you will get where its going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ddlAppealList.SelectedValue is return as which column you mapped from Datasoure Table into ddlAppealList.ValueMember otherwise without datasource assign you get Default value null.

ddlAppealList.SelectedValue is a object,so hold any data type.

you try out best option to use,

```
int.TryParse or int.Parse
```

before convert the ddlAppealList.SelectedValue into string variable as Example,

```
string str=Convert.ToString(ddlAppealList.SelectedValue);
int nSelectedValue;
if(int.TryParse(str,out nSelectedValue)
lblCompNameDisplay.Text = nSelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

string myString = myInt.ToString();

Answer (score -1):

please find below code

```
using System; 
int ddlValue = Int32.Parse(ddlAppealList.SelectedValue.ToString());
lblCompNameDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(ddlValue);
```